# Component's are overlapping when placed one below the other in angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have **2 components** called 1) `add-customer` 2)`edit-customer`

I am displaying these two components in **app.component.html** file using their respective selectors as shown in below code.

```
<app-add-customer></app-add-customer>
<app-edit-customer></app-edit-customer>
```

Here the issue is,The  **edit-customer** component is slightly overlapping **add-customer** component  as shown in below image.

[image]

I think i am missing some css,I tried with **position** property, still no result.Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-acnngh?file=app/edit-customer/edit-customer.component.html) link.

Comment: you want to move edit component ?

Comment: I want to move `edit-customer` component below the `add-customer` component. You can see in the image the **save & cancel** button belongs to 'add-customer' component still they are displaying unde 'edit-customer'.

Comment: check the answer

Comment: You have given margin-bottom, i don't want align them using margin property. any how i got the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

That's because your `.btn-sec` div has `float: right;` style.
Change that to `text-align: right;` and it wont overlap.